# Rotate a Line in a coordinate system

Tags: c#, graphics, rotation, 2d

I want to rotate a Line in a random angle alpha.

So Ive got the coordinates of the line: e.g. (10,20     20,30).
And the user gives an input e.g. 45.

Note that the coordinate system is not a regular one. I mean: the X-axis (horizontal) goes as usual positive in the right direction. But the Y-Axis(vertical) goes positive for the down-direction.

So a point that is usually at (2|-3) is at (2|3) in my coordinate system.

The line shall be now rotated in that angle 45 degree. 
My thought is to move the line first to the origin of the coordinate system, then rotate it(simply just moving the point that is not located at the origin), and then move it back to the old position.

```
**// moving the line to the origin of the coordinate system**    

int movedX1 = 0;
int movedY1 = 0;
int movedX2;
int movedY2;

if ((movedX2 = x2 - x1)<0)
{
movedX2 *= -1;
};
if ((movedY2 = y2 - y1) < 0)
{
movedY2 *= -1;
};

string newX1 = movedX1.ToString();
string newY1 = movedY1.ToString();
string newX2 = movedX2.ToString();
string newY2 = movedY2.ToString();

GIO.setItemProperty(item, "PointList", "\"" + newX1 + ", " + newY1 + "   " 
+ newX2 + ", " + newY2 + "\"");

MessageBox.Show("Moved Coordinates: "+ newX1 + ", " + newY1 + "   " + 
newX2 + ", " + newY2 );

**// now the Point that is not in the origin should be moved so the line 
// turns X degrees.**

double inputAngle, ind0_0, ind0_1, ind1_0, ind1_1;

inputAngle= Convert.ToDouble(txtWinkel.Text);

ind0_0 = Math.Cos(inputAngle/ Math.PI * 180);
ind0_1 = Math.Sin(inputAngle/ Math.PI * 180);
ind1_0 = Math.Sin(inputAngle/ Math.PI * 180);
ind1_1 = Math.Cos(inputAngle/ Math.PI * 180);

double finalX2 = -(ind0_0 * movedX2 - ind0_1 * movedY2);
double finalY2 = -(ind1_0 * movedX2 + ind1_1 * movedY2);
```

I think that the calculation is actually right, but the calculation is in radians and I dont know how to put that in degree level.

Comment: two rotate a line, you need 4 things: the line, given by 2 points, a fixed spot you rotate around (my be this (0;0) for you ?) and an angle to rotate around.
Then you convert the points you like to rotate into radial-coordinate(distance and angle to the rotation point), you modify the angle by adding the rotation, and at the end you return from the radial-coordinates, to cartesian coordinates.
You never need anything in degrees in this process.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: It is another program, but thats not the point. so I can insert the coordinates iinto that program... thats not the problem. the problem is, how to calculate out of the input the level degree...

Comment: And yes the rotating around point is (0|0)

Comment: What exactly is your question? I can see three potential problems: `if ((movedX2 = x2 - x1)<0) movedX2 *= -1;` - why are you doing that? Just keep the negative number. `inputAngle/ Math.PI * 180` - you need the other way around: `inputAngle * Math.PI / 180`. `finalX2 = -...` - why is it negative? And finally, you need to move it back: `finalX = ... + x1`.